# perl; what is this? for(1..$scalar_name)

Tags: perl

I'm reading a perl code to distill what it's doing, but can't figure out what `1..$scalar_name` in these lines is doing

```
my $scalar_name = scalar @array_name;
push @zeroes, 0 for(1..$scalar_name);
```

Thank you!

Comment: $scalar_name is a number n that represents the entries in the array @array_name. 1..$scalar_name means: 1 to $scalar_name.

Comment: That makes an array `@zeroes` filled with zeroes, as many zeroes as the number of items in `@array_name` (repeating `0` from `1` to size of `array_name`)

Comment: `my @zeros = (0) x @array_name;` does the same but avoids the explicit loop and is thus faster and more efficient, btw.

Comment: @Shawn, Thank you!
When getting to the task of making my own scripts and pipelines out of the scrips that I inhereted from my predecessor I'll definitely take this into account!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two dots `..` is a [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

> Binary ".." is the range operator, which is really two different operators depending on the context. In list context, it returns a list of values counting (up by ones) from the left value to the right value. If the left value is greater than the right value then it returns the empty list. The range operator is useful for writing foreach (1..10) loops and for doing slice operations on arrays.

Your code takes the number of elements of the array and creates a new array with the same number of zeros.

Comment: Ah, thank you!
That was a lot simpler than I thought!

Comment: In practice, no range operator is used in `for ($x .. $y)` as an optimization. This forms a simple counting loop.